# web deployement

Tags: php, html, version-control, web, workflow

I have a home headless server for dev+testing.For small projects my workflow is just drag throught sftp several files to a temp folder on my workmachine and then upload them to the "production" server. But now I face a big project that dapends on the release files has no changes. Production server is a shared hosting with apache. I don't want to waste time neither bandwidth. Seems that a revision control software could suit the purpose. But i can't install software above apache. What could the workflow be? Is there any "subversion","git", (...) for web deployement?Any other solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Is there any 'subversion','git', (...) for web deployement?"  Yes....they're known by the names of subversion and git, respectively.

Comment: If it's a shared server, then creating a network connection to it and doing a revision control update may not be possible. Failing that, maybe your host supports `rsync` - that would do very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You need ssh (or direct) access to do this(svn or git deploy) but you can use phing deployment and composer for the dependencies.

https://github.com/composer/composer

http://www.phing.info/trac/

Answer (score 0):

You can use rsync the same way you use sftp (obviusly, the server has to support it) and is instantaneos for something like 65000 files (wen only maybe 2 have changed).

Something like GIT or SVN can be much better, and have other features, but if you want something simple, and you are a single dev, you can use a backup system + rsync + a diff tool like Meld or WinMerge.

Possible workflow:

- You develop in workstation A, in folder "dev/".
- You review changes, and transfer changes with diff/winmerge to folder "rc/".
- You upload "rc/" to "public_html/" in the public server with rsync.

Wen you copy changes from "dev/" to "rc/" you re-read then, and check if make sense, only transfering the changes that make sense and don't make rc/ unstable. If all changes are safe, you can do it just a single button.

This is a inferior system to using something based on git/svn.

Answer (score 0):

*VCS-systems* and *Deploy-systems* are, really, different classes for different jobs and tasks. You have to ask, "How to deploy web application", I think.

Phing already was recommended, from other side you can (using tools of your SCM, if any used) export changed files after each changeset and transfer on shared hosting using any available transport. Can't see problem here.

> For small projects my workflow is just drag throught sftp several
>   files to a temp folder on my workmachine and then upload them to the
>   "production" server

is perfectly applicable to big projects also